# Single formula to search column and return corresponding fields

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

[image: Screenshot]

Am having issues creating a single formula to search the billionaires list by name and autofill the rank, age, net worth, and citizenship field in the search spreadsheet.
This is the formula I have written:

```
=INDEX(bil!A2:bil!A12, MATCH(B3, bil!B2:bil!B12,0))
```

I am a newbie at Excel and don't have much experience with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is fine conceptually, but your range references are messed up. To refer to a range of cells on another sheet, you only need to reference the sheet name once, like so:

```
bil!A2:A12
```

Answer (score 0):

You need VLOOKUP. I'm not going to do your homework for you, but here's the basics:

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)
```

Configure the arguments as follows:

**lookup_value** is the value, or a cell reference to the value, you want matched.

**table_array** is a reference to the cell range which has the data you're interested in. This should include the column in which lookup_value may be found, as well as the column that has the data you want to get returned. However, it is important to be aware that *VLOOKUP will only search for lookup_value in the leftmost column of table_array*.

**col_index** is the column number where the data you want returned will be. This starts with the leftmost column in table_array as 1, and increments upwards to the right. Negative values and zero are not valid.

**range_lookup** is a TRUE or FALSE selection to state whether you want to allow approximate matches. I always set this to FALSE for reliability. There's probably some use cases for TRUE, but I'm not sure exactly how Excel determines what's an "approximate" match. This is the only optional argument for this formula - if omitted, it will be treated as TRUE.